# Converting BCD Truth Table to Output Functions Using K-Maps

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, converter, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

To be honest, I'm just looking to see if I'm on the right track with a certain question.

[image: Question]

This here would be my answer for the K-Map for the "H" output function and im just curious if im on the right path here. Any input would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Yes.. you are on the right path.. proceed to remaining functions

Comment: You are on the right path. However your equation for H can be simplified to A+C+BD+B'D'